# How L1 norm select features?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

It has been often said that L1 regularization helps in feature selection? How the L1 norm does that?

And also why L2 normalization is not able to do that?

Comment: which model are you referring to in which L1 norm helps in feature selection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning please notice `L1` and `L2` regularization may not always work like that, there are various quirks and it depends on applied strength and other factors.

First of all, we will consider [Linear Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) as the simplest case.

Secondly it's easiest to consider only two weights for this problem to get some intuition.

Now, let's introduce a simple constraint: sum of both weights has to be equal to `1.0` (e.g. first weight `w1=0.2` and second `w2=0.8` or any other combination).

And the last assumptions:

- `x1` feature has perfect positive correlation with target (e.g. `1.0 * x1 = y`, where `y` is our target)
- `x2` has **almost** perfect positive correlation with target (e.g. `0.99 * x2 = y`)

(`alpha` (meaning regularization strength) will be set to `1.0` for both `L1` and `L2` in order no to clutter the picture further).

### L2

#### Weights values

For two variables (weights) and `L2` regularization we would have the following formula:

```
alpha * (w1^2 + w2^2)/2 (mean of their squares)
```

Now, we would like to minimize the above equation as it's part of the [cost function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/179027).

One can easily see both has to be set to `0.5` (remember, their sum has to be equal `1.0`!), because `0.5 ^ 2 + 0.5 ^ 2 = 0.5`. For any other two values summing to `1` we would get a greater value (e.g. `0.8 ^ 2 + 0.2 ^ 2 = 0.64 + 0.68`), hence `0.5` and `0.5` is optimal solution.

#### Target predictions

In this case we are pretty close **for all data points**, because:

```
0.5 * 1.0 + 0.5 + 0.99 = 0.995 (of `y`)
```

So we are "off" only by `0.005` for each sample. What this means is that regularization on weights has greater effect on cost function than this small difference (that's why `w1` wasn't chosen as the only variable and the values were "split").

BTW. Exact values above will differ slightly (e.g. `w1` `~0.49` but it's easier to follow along this way I think).

#### Final insight

With `L2` regularization two similar weights tend to be "split" in half as it minimizes the regularization penalty

### L1

#### Weights values

This time it will be even easier: for two variables (weights) and `L1` regularization we would have the following formula:

```
alpha * (|w1| + |w2|)/2 (mean of their absolute values)
```

This time it doesn't matter what `w1` or `w2` is set to (as long as their sum has to be equal to `1.0`), so `|0.5| + |0.5| = |0.2| + |0.8| = |1.0| + |0.0|...` (and so on).

In this case `L1` regularization will prefer `1.0`, the reason below

#### Target predictions

As the distribution of weights does not matter in this case it's loss value we are after (under the `1.0` sum constraint). For perfect predictions it would be:

```
1.0 * 1.0 + 0.0 * 0.99 = 1.0
```

This time we are not "off" at all and it's "best" to choose just `w1`, no need for `w2` in this case.

#### Final insight

With `L1` regularization similar weights tend to be zeroed out in favor of the one connected to feature being better at predicting final target with lowest coefficient.

BTW. If we had `x3` which would once again be correlated positively with our values to predict and described by equation

0.1 * x3 = y

Only `x3` would be chosen with weight equal to `0.1`

### Reality

In reality there is almost never "perfect correlation" of variables, there are many features interacting with each other, there are hyperparameters and imperfect optimizers amongst many other factors.

This simplified view should give you an intuition to "why" though.

Answer (score 0):

A common application of your question is in different types of regression. Here is a link that explains the difference between Ridge (L2) and Lasso (L1) regression:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/866/when-should-i-use-lasso-vs-ridge